# How to port commits from one Git branch to another, but without some files

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have a branch, `testing`, that contains tons of changes to files in `a/`, and also to files in `b/`.

I want to port all of the commits from `testing` onto my `master` branch. However, I want to only port the changes to `a/`. On the `master` branch, `b/` is in `.gitignore`, and should not show up in the history.

I'd like to do this in a way that preserves commit messages, authorship, and ideally timestamps.

I believe [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), or its recommended replacement, [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/), might be the right tools for this. However, they seem targeted at whole-repository operations, not porting between branches, so figuring out how to use them for my purpose brings me to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was pretty easy with `git filter-repo`: I just needed to use the `--refs` option.

I created a new branch, `testing2`, from `testing`:

```sh
git checkout testing
git checkout -b testing2
```

then ran

```sh
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path b/ --refs testing2
```

Then I merged the newly-rewritten `testing2` on top of master:

```sh
git checkout master
git merge testing2
```